# Representation of comment tag

Tags: html, dom

From URL I am extracting the content in that all the tag coming in one page. I want to filter the comment tag before submitting this content. I filtered some tag say

,  which is not required to me. However I couldn't find any interpretation for comment tag. I can catch the node element for comment tag. So i want tag representation for comment tag.

HTML comments are (normally) ignored by the browser: they are not used to build the DOM tree. So I want an interpretation of comment tag so that I can able to filtered it out before sending the form

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain in more detail what you are doing and possibly show some code?

Comment: Retagged. The question is not really about behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML comments are ([normally](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)) ignored by the browser: they are not used to build the DOM tree. Thus they are not a good place to put information that should be sent back to the server.

I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish but you should probably be using hiddend fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
```